Does this slight modification alter the limit of this sequence?
Let $x\in\mathbf R$.  Is the following true?
\begin{align}
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[1- \frac{x^2}{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{3n}}\right)\right]^{n/2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[1- \frac{x^2}{n}\right]^{n/2}
\end{align}
This result would facilitate proving that a certain PDF converges pointwise to the standard normal density.  Graphing both sides for large $n$ seems consistent with the statement being true, but searching for sufficient conditions under which a composed pair of sequences $f_n(g_n(x))$ converges to the composite of their limits $f(g(x))$ has not yielded conditions that can be applied to this particular case.

This is a good question

Yes. Both are equal to $e^{-x^2/2}$

@jgd1729 Thanks -- that is what I thought, but does this follow from any well-known theorems in real analysis?  It's non-obvious to me because of the lack of uniform convergence of the right hand side.

You can just use l'Hopital's rule to evaluate each one. Regarding any theorems showing something more general here, I don't know of any off the top of my head. It's not immediately obvious to me that these two should be equal based on the modification alone. Actually calculating the limits is the only way I currently see of doing this

It depends if you just need the limit or a bit more

@ClaudeLeibovici Although "a bit more" would be interesting, I just need the limit.

Retracting my vote to close after you edited the question.

Can you work with the generalt result stating that if $a_n\to 1$ and $b_n\to\infty$, then
$$a_n^{b_n}\to e^C,$$
where
$$C=\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n(a_n-1))?$$ Need to assume the limit $C$ exists, IIRC.

@JyrkiLahtonen I'm not familiar with this, and I'll think about it.  Do you have a reference to a text where this general result is stated?

$$A^B=(1+(A-1))^B=\left(1+\frac1{1/(A-1)}\right)^B=\left(\left(1+\frac1{1/(A-1)}\right)^{1/(A-1)}\right)^{B(A-1)}$$
holds unless something exceptional happens at some step. Here $1/|A-1|\to\infty$. Of course, using the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}(1+\frac1x)^x=e.$$ Observe the $\pm$ in $\pm\infty$.

(cont'd) Like you need to assume that $A\neq1$. This translates into the requirement that the stated formula needs extra care, if $a_n=1$ for infinitely many choices of $n$. I apologize for omitting that.

Taking a logarithm and applying l'Hopital gives
\begin{align}
  y &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[1- \frac{x^2}{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{3n}}\right)\right]^{n/2} \\
\ln y &= \ln\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[1- \frac{x^2}{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{3n}}\right)\right]^{n/2} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln \left[1- \frac{x^2}{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{3n}}\right)\right]^{n/2} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac n2 \ln \left[1- \frac{x^2}{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{3n}}\right)\right] \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac  {\ln \left[1- \frac{x^2}{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{3n}}\right)\right]}{\frac 2n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac  {\left[1- \frac{x^2}{n}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{3n}}\right)\right]^{-1}\left[\frac{x^2}{n^2}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{3n}}\right) + \frac{x^2}{n}\left(\frac{x}{3\sqrt{3}n^{3/2}}\right) \right]}{\frac {-2}{n^2}} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac  {-x^2(9n^{3/2}+3\sqrt{3} nx)}{18n^{3/2}-18\sqrt{n}x^2-4\sqrt{3}x^3} \\
&= \frac{-x^2}{2}
\end{align}
Exponentiating then gives
$$
y=e^{-x^2/2}
$$
The right hand side can be done similarly but is much simpler.

This is great; thanks.  I was taking logarithms, but it didn't occur to me to chain this with l'Hopital.
